# LDAP Routing / Connection

Tags: active-directory, ldap

If I am on say domain **example1.com** and want to query for users in the AD catalogue of **example2.com** with an LDAP connect string of **LDAP://DC=example2, DC=com** how is the connection made?

Is the LDAP connection from the client application to the DC of **example1.com** and then a DC to DC connection between the two domains to proxy queries or is the LDAP connection made direct from the client application to the DC in **example2.com**?

I am having a number of connection issues when using the **DirectorySearcher** component in C# and suspect it may be trying to connect directly to the DC of the target domain rather than its local DC.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two scenarios based on you can find your solution

1. In theory, if the domains are in the same forest, you should get the user distinguished name (DN) from the Global Catalog. The GC has a partial (read-only) replica of all domains in the forest. In theory, you would specify the GC: provider instead of the LDAP: provider, and let the system select the best GC. You should not have to specify the DC. Once you have the DN, if the domains are trusted, you should be able to bind to the object and modify it (if you have permissions).

   It can also be done with `Get-ADUser _-Server DOMAINCONTROLLER -credential $NULL_ -filter {samaccountname -eq $SourceAccount} | Set-ADUser -Enabled $True`

   The -server propertie points to the domain controller and the -  credential $NULL will prompt for a Domain Admin ID in the other domain to use.
2. Regarding on the cross-forest/cross-domain directory query/access scenario.

   you might need to make sure the two domains (your current domain and the target domain to query data) have two-way trust relationship. Here are some web articles and threads talking on similar topics:

   #Cross Forest LDAP Query and sub domains.
   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6257f7d1-5a07-4652-af0c-4550ddffe1c3/cross-forest-ldap-query-and-sub-domains

   #Querying Groups and Users across multiple domains with LDAP in C# .NET
   http://jokecamp.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/querying-groups-and-users-across-multiple-domains-with-ldap-in-c-net/

   A common mistake that is made on cross-forest/crosss-domain queries is not properly specifying the full domain name in the search base of the query.

> Example:   two domains domain1.com, domain2.com. The common mistake is
> to query domain1.com for users by sepecifying "DC=COM" as the search
> base in the LDAP query....thinking that the query will simply look in
> both domain1 and domain2, this is not the case. This is a mistake
> because DC=COM does not actually exist on a partition, only
> DC=domain1,DC=com and DC=domain2,DC=com exists.      The thing to
> remember is that even though you are querying users from another domain
> (not on the DC you are directing the query to), you must specify that
> full domain as the search base, just like you would to without it
> being cross-forest/domain. What make it a cross-forest/domain query is
> the fact that you are not going to correct DC.

Reference for above answer is taken from here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90498e4b-51e4-4552-869d-2096a063f43d/cross-domain-ad-query?forum=aspactivedirectory